# Am I creating look at and perspective matrices correcly?

Tags: c, opengl, matrix

I have coded OpenGl Super Bible's example https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code/blob/master/src/grass/grass.cpp
with C and freeglut. Result has been that points are outside of the view.

Do I calculate and use look at and perspective matrices correctly?

Part of the Rendering function:

```
Matrix proj=CreateProjectionMatrix(45.0f,CurrentWidth/CurrentHeight,0.1f,1000.0f);

float t=glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME)*0.002f;
float eye[]={sinf(t)*550.0f,25.0f,cosf(t)*550.0f};
float center[]={0.0f,-50.0f,0.0f};
float up[]={0.0f,1.0f,0.0f};
Matrix look=lookAt(eye,center,up);

Matrix final=MultiplyMatrices(&proj,&look);

glUniformMatrix4fv(UniformsMvpMatrix,1,GL_FALSE,final.m);
```

Calculations:

```
typedef struct Matrix{
  GLfloat m[16];
}Matrix;

Matrix CreateProjectionMatrix(float fovy,float aspect,float Znear,float Zfar){
    // Array index in the matrix
    //  _          _
    // | 0 4  8  12 |
    // | 1 5  9  13 |
    // | 2 6 10  14 |
    // |_3 7 11  15_|
    //
    Matrix out;
    float tanhalffovy = tanf(DegreesToRadians(fovy/2));
    out.m[ 0]=1/(aspect*tanhalffovy);
    out.m[ 5]=1/(tanhalffovy);
    out.m[10]=(Zfar+Znear)/(Znear-Zfar);
    out.m[11]=(2*Zfar*Znear)/(Znear-Zfar);
    out.m[14]=-1;
    out.m[ 1]=0;
    out.m[ 2]=0;
    out.m[ 3]=0;
    out.m[ 4]=0;
    out.m[ 6]=0;
    out.m[ 7]=0;
    out.m[ 8]=0;
    out.m[ 9]=0;
    out.m[12]=0;
    out.m[13]=0;
    out.m[15]=0;
    return out;
}

Matrix lookAt(float eye[3],float center[3],float up[3]){
    // Array index in the matrix
    //  _          _
    // | 0 4  8  12 |
    // | 1 5  9  13 |
    // | 2 6 10  14 |
    // |_3 7 11  15_|
    //
    double help=sqrt(up[0]*up[0]+up[1]*up[1]+up[2]*up[2]);
    float upN[3];
    upN[0]=up[0]/help;
    upN[1]=up[1]/help;
    upN[2]=up[2]/help;

    float f[3];
    f[0]=(center[0]-eye[0]);
    f[1]=(center[1]-eye[1]);
    f[2]=(center[2]-eye[2]);
    help=sqrt(f[0]*f[0]+f[1]*f[1]+f[2]*f[2]);
    f[0]/=help;
    f[1]/=help;
    f[2]/=help;

    float s[3];
    s[0]=f[1]*upN[2]-upN[1]*f[2];
    s[1]=f[2]*upN[0]-upN[2]*f[0];
    s[2]=f[0]*upN[1]-upN[0]*f[1];

    float u[3];
    u[0]=s[1]*f[2]-f[1]*s[2];
    u[1]=s[2]*f[0]-f[2]*s[0];
    u[2]=s[0]*f[1]-f[0]*s[1];

    Matrix out={{s[0],s[1],s[2],0, u[0],u[1],u[2],0, f[0],f[1],f[2],0, -eye[0],-eye[1],-eye[2],1}};
   return out;
}

Matrix MultiplyMatrices(const Matrix* m1, const Matrix* m2){    
    Matrix out;
    // First column
    out.m[ 0]=(m1->m[0])*(m2->m[0])+(m1->m[4])*(m2->m[1])+(m1->m[ 8])*(m2->m[2])+(m1->m[12])*(m2->m[3]);
    out.m[ 1]=(m1->m[1])*(m2->m[0])+(m1->m[5])*(m2->m[1])+(m1->m[ 9])*(m2->m[2])+(m1->m[13])*(m2->m[3]);
    out.m[ 2]=(m1->m[2])*(m2->m[0])+(m1->m[6])*(m2->m[1])+(m1->m[10])*(m2->m[2])+(m1->m[14])*(m2->m[3]);
    out.m[ 3]=(m1->m[3])*(m2->m[0])+(m1->m[7])*(m2->m[1])+(m1->m[11])*(m2->m[2])+(m1->m[15])*(m2->m[3]);
    // Second column
    out.m[ 4]=(m1->m[0])*(m2->m[4])+(m1->m[4])*(m2->m[5])+(m1->m[ 8])*(m2->m[6])+(m1->m[12])*(m2->m[7]);
    out.m[ 5]=(m1->m[1])*(m2->m[4])+(m1->m[5])*(m2->m[5])+(m1->m[ 9])*(m2->m[6])+(m1->m[13])*(m2->m[7]);
    out.m[ 6]=(m1->m[2])*(m2->m[4])+(m1->m[6])*(m2->m[5])+(m1->m[10])*(m2->m[6])+(m1->m[14])*(m2->m[7]);
    out.m[ 7]=(m1->m[3])*(m2->m[4])+(m1->m[7])*(m2->m[5])+(m1->m[11])*(m2->m[6])+(m1->m[15])*(m2->m[7]);
    // Third column
    out.m[ 8]=(m1->m[0])*(m2->m[8])+(m1->m[4])*(m2->m[9])+(m1->m[ 8])*(m2->m[10])+(m1->m[12])*(m2->m[11]);
    out.m[ 9]=(m1->m[1])*(m2->m[8])+(m1->m[5])*(m2->m[9])+(m1->m[ 9])*(m2->m[10])+(m1->m[13])*(m2->m[11]);
    out.m[10]=(m1->m[2])*(m2->m[8])+(m1->m[6])*(m2->m[9])+(m1->m[10])*(m2->m[10])+(m1->m[14])*(m2->m[11]);
    out.m[11]=(m1->m[3])*(m2->m[8])+(m1->m[7])*(m2->m[9])+(m1->m[11])*(m2->m[10])+(m1->m[15])*(m2->m[11]);
    // Fourth
    out.m[12]=(m1->m[0])*(m2->m[12])+(m1->m[4])*(m2->m[13])+(m1->m[ 8])*(m2->m[14])+(m1->m[12])*(m2->m[15]);
    out.m[13]=(m1->m[1])*(m2->m[12])+(m1->m[5])*(m2->m[13])+(m1->m[ 9])*(m2->m[14])+(m1->m[13])*(m2->m[15]);
    out.m[14]=(m1->m[2])*(m2->m[12])+(m1->m[6])*(m2->m[13])+(m1->m[10])*(m2->m[14])+(m1->m[14])*(m2->m[15]);
    out.m[15]=(m1->m[3])*(m2->m[12])+(m1->m[7])*(m2->m[13])+(m1->m[11])*(m2->m[14])+(m1->m[15])*(m2->m[15]);

    return out;
}
```

I am 99.9% sure that shader is the same as in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues with your code:

1. It is not really clear which matrix storage layout convention you are using.

   Your `lookAt` code put the `-eye` translation into the elements 12 to 14, implying you use column-major layout together with the standard GL's `matrix * vector` multiplication order in the shader. However, your projection matrix is defined transposed to that convention. Elements 11 and 14 should be swapped.
2. Your `lookAt` function is wrong:

   The view matrix should transform the world space  to an eye space where the camera is at the center and looking into `-z` direction. This can be interpreted as either *moving all objects* with respect to a fixed camera, or as defining the new view coordinate system with respect to the world coordinates. You'll end up with the formula `R * T(-eye)` in both cases. In the first interpretation, this means that we first move all objects by `-eye` (so that the point `eye` ends up at the center), and then rotate around that new center such that the lookAt direction is rotated into the `-z` axis, and the `up` vector to `+y`.

   However, your `lookAt` matrix doesn't do that. Your matrix can be decomposed to `T(-eye) * R^-1`. So first of all, your `R` is not the rotation you need: If you muliply your matrix by the `-z` axis vector `(0,0,-1,0)^T`, you will just select the third column and negate it, so you'll end up with `-f`. But your forward direction vector should be `f`, so you forgot to negate `f` before putting it into the matrix.

   The second issue is that the rotation is actually *inverted*. If you negate the third column, you'll end up with `V * (0 0 -1 0)^T  = (f 0)^T`, but that is the opposite transformation direction then you need. You have to build a rotation that results in `V * (f 0)^T = (0 0 -1 0)`. Now the nice thing about rotation matrices is that they are orthogonal, so that `R^-1 = R^T`.That means you can simply transpose your rotation matrix to invert it.

   However, you cannot just transpose your view matrix. And this brings us to the last issue: You simply write the translation part `-eye` into the fourth column. Conceptually, this means you do `V=T(-eye) * R`, that is, you apply the translation as the *last* step. However, as we have seen before, we must apply the translation *first*. So to completely fix your matrix, you build `R^T` first, by transposing the rotation parts, that is, writing the `s`, `u` and `-f` vectors as `rows` into the matrix, and finally you *multiply* that matrix by a simple translation matrix with `T(-eye)`.